# Github API not accepting Unicode characters in JSON format

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, github-api

I have an Exception that occurs when I read from a Unicode charactered file and try to create a Github issue via API for the occurred Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./item.py", line 320, in <module>
    auto_issue(opt.hashToCrack, e, e.message)
  File "/home/baal/bin/python/settings.py", line 480, in auto_issue
    _failure(issue, hashed_string, error)
  File "/home/baal/bin/python/github/create_issue.py", line 109, in _failure
    urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 435, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 473, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 422: Unprocessable Entity
```

I've done some research and come to the conclusion that this happens when there is Unicode characters in the Exception information. How I create the Github issues looks like this:

```
def _failure(issue, hashed_string, error):

    def __create_issue_ext():
        retval = []
        for _ in range(5):
            retval.append(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))
        return ''.join(retval)

    issue_title = "Unhandled Exception {}({})".format(issue, __create_issue_ext())
    issue_data = {
        "title": issue_title,
        "body": open("{}/lib/github/issue_template".format(os.getcwd())).read().format(
            type(error).__name__, (error.args, error.message), platform.platform(),
            hashed_string, sys.argv
        )
    }
    req = urllib2.Request(
        url="https://api.github.com/repos/<name>/<project>/issues", data=json.dumps(issue_data),
        headers={"Authorization": "token {}".format(__handle(__get_encoded_string()))})

    urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
    lib.settings.LOGGER.info(
        "Your issue has been created with the title '{}'.".format(
            issue_title
        )
    )
```

Now this works, as long as there are no Unicode characters in the Exception string. So my question is, is there a way I can either, allow the Unicode into the JSON format, or strip the Exception string of the Unicode characters before adding it to the JSON format?

Comment: Is it possible to run your scripts on python 3+? Most of the problems in handling unicode is taken care in python 3.

Comment: @Poonacha Nope only 2.7.x

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request) you should `urllib.urlencode` your data.